# Android push notifications to a custom list of subscribers of a topic using Amazon SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm currently working on an application build on AWS. At first, the application was on Parse server and the push notifications were not a problem but then, when I migrated to AWS I encountered some issues with that.

As far as I read from this link http://aws.amazon.com/articles/9156883257507082 I learned that I need to create a topic to subscribe users by creating **endpoints** using the **device tokens** from where they are currently logged in. 
I will have many users, and the notifications will be sent to all endpoints from a topic.

The problem is when I want to send a notification I want to exclude some users from a topic for receiving that, for example, when a user posts something I will not send a notification to him too. This is available also when I have a custom audience to send notifications to. I could create a topic for every event notification to be sent but I don't think this is a efficient method.

Is there a possibility to do that or Amazon does not even support this feature? Until now I didn't find anything on internet that can help me solve this problem and I hope I'll find here someone who worked with this. 
Thank you for your time!

**Plus** : I also found a similar question here [Send Push Notifications using Amazon SNS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754885/send-push-notifications-using-amazon-sns-service?rq=1) but I still don't have a certain answer or some links about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've found in AWS documentation, it states that

> Send messages directly to a specific device by calling the Publish function with the device’s ARN. **You can easily scale this to handle millions of users by storing the endpoint ARNs in Amazon DynamoDB and using multi-threaded code on the server.**

Thus, to be able to filter users that receive notifications and not send bulk messages to all users subscribed to a topic, you need to send messages using the device's ARNs.

You can find more info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/aws/category/amazon-simple-notification-service/?nc1=h_ls)

Comment: This is true. I could do that and I thought about this solution but I didn't consider it to be efficient. I think that for a million users it will take too much time to send the notifications in this way.

Comment: Again, to quote from the documentation, "You can easily scale this to handle millions of users". I don't know, maybe replace the service if it doesn't fit your needs

Comment: @OanaBejenaru u can talk to AWS support team to include that feature. As Ddsix says it is not possible through SNS what you are looking for